# Running Java Applet Offline

Tags: java, web

I need to use the following applet: http://www.babynamewizard.com/name-mapper

However, it won't run in any of my browsers, despite the latest version of Java being installed.

Is there a way to download the .jar so I can run it offline?
I searched the source but couldn't find it nor a .class file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Running it in a browser != running it online

Comment: Use JNLP. When you click the link to the jnlp file it will create a link on your desktop and install the app locally, so you'll have it available without having to be connected to internet.

Comment: If you plug the applet url directly into appletviewer it runs. `appletviewer http://namemapper.babynamewizard.com/namemapper/namemapper.htm`.

Comment: I did all that work for nothing, it's really simple.

Answer (score 1):

Edited** *Check out comment from Petesh first, check if that works for you, if not proceed.*

Ok, here goes nothing.

You'll the applet that you want to run is inside an IFrame with src set to "http://namemapper.babynamewizard.com/namemapper/namemapper.htm"

Which means the base URL for any of the resources with the relative path is 
"http://namemapper.babynamewizard.com/namemapper/"

And the applet tag inside there is

```
<applet code="names.state.ui.StateVisualizationApplet" width="762" height="523" archive="states005.jar" title="undefined">
    <param name="nameListURL" value="legal-names-2010.txt">
    <param name="mapURL" value="state-outline.txt">
    <param name="sortURL" value="name-sort3.txt">
    <param name="dataURL" value="data2010">
</applet>
```

So the JAR URL is

1. http://namemapper.babynamewizard.com/namemapper/states005.jar

You'll have to download following files along with the JAR file.

1. http://namemapper.babynamewizard.com/namemapper/states005.jar
2. http://namemapper.babynamewizard.com/namemapper/legal-names-2010.txt
3. http://namemapper.babynamewizard.com/namemapper/state-outline.txt
4. http://namemapper.babynamewizard.com/namemapper/name-sort3.txt

Then create an HTML file (suppose test.html) in the same directory as the above downloaded files with following code.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <applet code="names.state.ui.StateVisualizationApplet" width="762" height="523" archive="states005.jar" title="undefined">
        <param name="nameListURL" value="legal-names-2010.txt">
        <param name="mapURL" value="state-outline.txt">
        <param name="sortURL" value="name-sort3.txt">
        <param name="dataURL" value="data2010">
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally you'll need to use AppletViewer. It comes with the JDK or JRE.
Go the directory of the above files and run following command

```
appletviewer test.html
```

It'll show you the applet, however this applet downloads files on the fly to search for names for example if we search Male, Max then it will try to download file.

**data2010/M/max.m.txt**

So it will have to present in the test.html's parent directory with the exact same path. That means you'll have to create the following directory structure

```
-data2010
---M
-----max.m.txt
```

You'll need to download the max.m.txt in the same way.

1. http://namemapper.babynamewizard.com/namemapper/data2010/M/max.m.txt

Finally you'll be able to search for Max. For any other names it will give an error, just look at the trace and download the file it needs.

It's hectic but it works.